# Does collection still exists in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I've tried finding documentation on how to create, view, delete, etc mongoose collections but couldn't find anything on it. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using the wrong words for searching, maybe because it is so part of mongoose that people just assume by default it is not needed to mention it directly. 
You can find information on the official documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html
You can also look for tutorials on websites. In general, when you study documents, that is enough, collection is a related topic. Just study how to create, delete....documents, and collections will come up! 
I hope that helps!